# assigning string to an int?

Tags: string, int

Working on this assignment for class and I'm not sure what this section means. We're supposed to create a program that prompts the user for commands and stores them but the commands and supposed to be ints but have letters in them. Not sure how to deal with this.

int getCommand()returns CMD_LET, CMD_DOC, CMD_PRINT, CMD_DO, CMD_HISTORY, or 
CMD_END to indicate what command it is.

Comment: best guess will be it could be a ENUM?

Comment: What programming language is this for?

Comment: When asking questions please make sure to add all the available information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ENUM to do the JOB and the ENUM maps between for instance CMD_LET=1,CMD_DOC=2 and so on, enum implementation should be almost the same in every programing language